# How to merge dict keys with sum of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 3 dicts

```
d1 = {"a":[1], "b":[2]}
d2 = {"b":[3], "d":[1]}
d3 = {"a":[4], "d":[2], "c":[3]}
```

How can we merge dict so that key can remain same and value will be sum of lists?

output

```
output = {"a":5, "b":5, "c":3, "d":3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a dict to store the partial sum.

```py
d1 = {"a": [1], "b": [2]}
d2 = {"b": [3], "d": [1]}
d3 = {"a": [4], "d": [2], "c": [3]}


def dict_sum(*dicts):
    merged = {}

    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            merged[k] = merged.setdefault(k, 0) + sum(v)

    return merged


print(dict_sum(d1, d2, d3))
```

Comment: you can use a `defaultdict` to reduce the `if/else` statement

Comment: @gold_cy good idea! :)